# regex double split

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

How Java regex expression should look like if I want to find two matches

```
1. NEW D City 
2. 1259669
```

From

```
Object No: NEW D City | Item ID: 1259669
```

I tried with

```
(?<=:\s)\w+
```

but it only get

```
 1. NEW
 2. 1259669
```

https://regex101.com/r/j5jwK2/1

Comment: What does your actual input data look like? Does it consist of lines with pairs like you are showing?

Comment: `(?<=:\s)\w+(\s+\w+)*`? But perhaps a proper ‘parser’ that splits on `|` and then maps with `:` (and trims) would be better.

Comment: Try `s.split("\\s*\\|?\\s*[^:|]+:\\s*")`, but a more appropriate approach is to match with `:\s*([^:|]+)` and trim `.group(1)`.

Comment: You may use: [`(?<=:\s)[^|]+(?=\s|\z)`](https://regex101.com/r/j5jwK2/2)

Comment: I'm not sure a regular expression is the right tool for this.

Comment: @jsageryd you will still need a regex to `split("\\|")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pattern to capture both values is simpler. Here is the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/5EfyHg/2) used :

```
Object No:([^|]*)\| Item ID: (\d*)
```

And a code generated by regex101 and adapted to match the output you want.

```
    final String regex = "Object No: ([^|]*)\\| Item ID: (\\d*)";
    final String string = "Object No: NEW D City | Item ID: 1259669";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(+ i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
1: NEW D City 
2: 1259669
```

A similar but more generec solution would be `[^:]*[:\s]*([^|]*)\|[^:]*[:\s]*(\d*)` (not perfect, I didn't try to do something efficient)

Answer (score 1):

You may use a combination of two splits:

```
String key = "Object No: NEW D City | Item ID: 1259669";
String[] parts = key.split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String part : parts) {
    String[] kvp = part.split(":\\s*");
    if (kvp.length == 2) {
        result.add(kvp[1]);
        System.out.println(kvp[1]); // demo
    }
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/3rDghL)

First, you split with `\\s*\\|\\s*` (a `|` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces) and then with `:\\s*`,  a colon followed with 0+ whitespaces.

Another approach is to use [`:\s*([^|]+)` pattern](https://regex101.com/r/7RtbKD/1) and grab and trim Group 1 value:

```
String s = "Object No: NEW D City | Item ID: 1259669";
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":\\s*([^|]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    result.add(m.group(1).trim());
    System.out.println(m.group(1).trim()); // For demo
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/oaTj1S). In this regex, the `([^|]+)` is a capturing group (pushing its contents into `matcher.group(1)`) that matches one or more (`+`) chars other than `|` (with the `[^|]` negated character class).